# ASP.NET MVC Can JSON object be passed to a controller with parameter with dynamic type parameter?

Tags: ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, jquery

I have code in my javascript, a ajax to post data:

```
$.ajax({
                url: '/Configurations/GetSelectedPageTranslation',
                type: 'POST',
                data: { inttype: $("#some").val(), objectType:{prop1: 'adsfa', prop2: 'asdf'}},
                success: function (result) {

                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('error');
                }
            });
```

In the contoller i have a method with signature:

```
public JsonResult GetSelectedPageTranslation(int inttype, dynamic objectType)
```

I can have the inttype correctly. However the objectType will not be null but if i do like objectType.prop1, it will throw error. If i will JSON.stringify the object type in the javascript, the objectType in the controller will have a string value.

Could this be possible to directly access the JSON data in the controller using the dynamic data type like this: objectType.prop1 ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no out of the box support for `dynamic` action arguments in MVC3.

However MVC is very extensible so you can add this functionality. What you need to do is to create a custom `IModelBinder` where you can do the JSON deserialization and build up a dynamic object.

Luckily this article: [Making MVC 3 a little more… dynamic](http://blog.duc.as/2011/06/07/making-mvc-3-a-little-more-dynamic/) is dealing with the exact same problem, so you can find also sample code and additional links there which should help you get started.