# How to post javascript objects with dynamic values to a mvc6 controller action

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-cosmosdb

In an asp.net5/mvc6 project I've created a page to edit documents from an Azure DocumentDB storage. I use jquery to post the data to a controller action.

A sample document from the database looks like this:

```
{  
    "key": "name1",  
    "value": 23
}
```

The property value can have different types (number, string, etc).

How can I keep this value dynamic when posting to the controller?
If I create a class like this works fine:

```
public class Setting
{
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "key")]
        public string Key { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "value")]
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In combination with a strongly typed parameter in the action:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Update(string collectionName, List<Setting> settings)
```

But now the value is always of type string.
I've tried to use JObject like this in the action:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Update(string collectionName, List<JObject> settings)
```

But then deserialized parameter settings inside the action has 'null' values for all properties:

```
{  "key": null,  "value": null}
```

//EDIT
Sample of the JS code posting to the action:

```
var data = {
    settings: [{ key: "test",  value: 123}]
}
$.ajax({
    url: 'controller/action',
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: data
});
```

Comment: Dynamic Json data passed to a controller took me to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11608262/3585500) which took me to [this link](http://blog.duc.as/2011/06/07/making-mvc-3-a-little-more-dynamic/) which took me to [this link](http://www.amazedsaint.com/2011/02/aspnet-mvc-dynamic-json-jquery.html). I noticed the MVC rev number kept getting lower and lower, so I stopped. =\

Comment: Where is your code which is posting these js objects to the action method ?

Comment: I edited the question to include the javascript

Answer (score 1):

Create a new viewmodel like this.

```
public class CollectionSettings
{
    public string CollectionName { set; get; }

    public List<Setting> Settings { set; get; }
}
```

and use that as the parameter of your action method

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Update([FromBody]  CollectionSettings model)
{
     // to do : Do something useful.
     return new JsonResult(new {Status = "Success"});
}
```

When you send your data from client side, be sure to convert the javascript object to Json string using `JSON.stringify` method and specify the `contentType` property value as `"application/json"`.

The below code should work fine.

```
var items = [];
var item1 = {
    "key": "name1",
    "value": 23
};
items.push(item1);

var model = { CollectionName: "test", Settings: items };

$.ajax({
    url: "@Url.Action("Update","Home")",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(model),
    contentType: "application/json"
}).done(function(r) {
    console.log(r);
});
```

Comment: The main issue is that I didn't want to use a strongly typed class such as 'Settings' because 'Value' can be of any type. With a strongly typed class it works fine, but value is always a string.